# Connect To SQL Server Express

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, ultidev

I have just started using SQL Server Express which syntactically the same as any other version of SQL Server, however, I am using my `web.config` file to create a connection string and connect with my code BUT I keep getting an error of

> An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occured in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code
>   Additional information: Can not open database "TestSQL" requested by the log-in. The login failed.

This is my syntax, and I am using windows authentication. If I log into the server itself with this info I can query away, but accessing through syntax it does not work.  Once my `con.Open()` line is hit the error is thrown.

`web.config`:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="SQLServer"
         connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=TestSQL;User ID=windowslogin; password=windowspassword; Integrated Security=True;"
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

C# code:

```
public DataSet GetItems()
{
    connectionstring = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SQLServer"].ConnectionString;
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionstring))
    {
      con.Open();
      using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("Select [field1] from [TestSql].[dbo].[Table1]", con));
      con.Close();
    }
}
```

**EDIT**:

I updated my `web.config` file to have this line of code and now it is presenting a new error shown below. Also, I am using UltiDev Web App Explorer to host not IIS

`web.config`:

```
<system.web>
    <identity impersonate="true" userName="windowsusername"   password="windowspassword" /?
</system.web>
```

And new error is:

> Additional information: Login failed for user ''.

Comment: does the database actually exists? does the user is allowed to access that database?

Comment: @Paolo - Yes the database exists, and yes the user has full access to that database

Comment: Drop the `user instance=true` from the connection string ...

Comment: @marc_s - same error of Login failed for user ''

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't pass a username and password when using `IntegratedSecurity`, and you can't use "windows" user accounts without it.  You need to use SQL logins (which is possible but not easy in SQL Express) or run the asp.net site (or [impersonate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xh507fc5.aspx)) a user that has the appropriate privileges to the database.

Comment: @D Stanley - I removed IntegratedSecurity and still the same error.  The username that I am passing has full access to the database...

Comment: @RashidAbib `User Id` and `Password` only work for _SQL Accounts_, not Windows accounts.  SQL Express will use the identity of the process trying to connect, which you can impersonate in ASP.NET (see the link in the answer).

Comment: @RashidAbib although Microsoft allows impersonation [Avoid using impersonation in ASP.Net](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/AvoidUsingImpersonationInASPNET.aspx).

Comment: @ErikPhilips - if it is recommended to avoid impersonation, how should this issue be handled in code?

Comment: @RashidAbib The [Application Pool Identity](http://www.iis.net/learn/manage/configuring-security/application-pool-identities) is modified to an account with the correct permissions or giving the correct permissions.

Comment: @DStanley based on the question itself, I would deduce that giving best practices is the recommended choice instead of giving exception case scenarios.